# nopcommerce assign product on attribute combinations

Tags: attributes, combinations, nopcommerce

I have a customer request that I would consider common for a cloth store, however not found a way to implemented it on NopCommerce.

The problem is that we stock t-shirts, jumpers etc in various colours and sizes, possibly separate the sex as well.

The actual products for sale are the primitive products with a particular design.

So Design 1, Design 2 ... Design N all use the same stock.

My idea was to be able to associate primitive products with a particular combination. 
That is not possible on nopcommerce. I can only associate a product to a particular attribute value.

Any idea/solution?

Comment: Group product doesnt work for you?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use  product attribute combinations in nopCommerce. Note: Attribute combinations are useful only when your Manage inventory method is set to Track inventory by product attributes

Comment: I have studied the mechanism and is not the case I want to cover.
Attribute combinations would create combinations for the current product. My case is that I want each attribute combination to define a product. this is the "primitive product" e.g. a t-shirt of size XL and color blue. I have inventory of 10 of these items and I use them to create the sale item which is product with Design Y name Y.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. Create a Product.
2. Create a product attributes ex. Image Squares. 3 values. Edit a value and upload square image and product image.
3. Create another product attribute. Image squares. 3 values. Edit a value and upload square image and product image.
4. add a condition on second attribute that if a value from first attribute is selected then only second product attribute should appear.
5. The first attribute selection will change the product image. The second won't.
6. Now if you remove the product image from first attribute, then second attribute selection will work.